# Magento Unable to load my custom layout through controller

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I have created a module with controller and model. But I am now trying to load a custom view where I can stuff all my PHP,css,js code into that PHTML file.

Here is my Block of Code

```
app\code\local\Soumen\Testmodule\controllers\IndexController.php

IndexController file


          public function indexAction()
          {
              echo "This is default";
           }

          public function sayHelloAction()
          {
              Mage::log('im in Controller');

              $this->loadLayout();
              $this->renderLayout();
             Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
          }


Config file

    app\code\local\Soumen\Testmodule\etc\config.xml

<config>


     <frontend>
        <routers>
              <Soumen_Testmodule>
                 <use>standard</use>
                 <args>
                      <module>Soumen_Testmodule</module>
                      <frontName>testmodule</frontName> 
                 </args>
              </Soumen_Testmodule>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <testmodule>
                    <file>testmodule.xml</file>
                </testmodule>
            </updates>
      </layout>
     </frontend>
</config>



app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\testmodule.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <testmodule_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="testmodule/test" name="test" template="testmodule/test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </testmodule_index_index>
</layout>`

app\code\local\Soumen\Testmodule\Block\Test.php


class Soumen_Testmodule_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
         public function getContent()
         {
             return "Hello World";
          }
     }

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\testmodule\test.phtml


<?php  echo $this->getContent();?>
```

Now when I call http://magento/testmodule... Then it displays the dufault page, 
 but should show Hello World . Can Someone help me out , that what wrong I am doing

Comment: Is that the entire config.xml and controller file? What do you see in your browser? Do you have a layout file? Can you post it? As this question stands, there's nowhere near enough information to start on it...

Comment: add your `testmodule.xml` from layout folder  and block code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <testmodule_index_sayHello>
  <reference name="content">
   <block name="testmodule" template="newpage/content.phtml"/>
  </reference>
 </testmodule_index_sayHello>
</layout>

Comment: I am able to see the default page of my theme, but I want to display the contents of my conent.phtml file , where I have added my HTML stuff

Comment: @SoumenKumarSaha for creating module you need to follow some basic steps.....as i written bellow (by Vishal Thakur). Just edit module name (Excellence_Test) as you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your `testmodule.xml` file use this

```
<testmodule_index_sayHello>
   <reference name="content"> 
       <block type="modulename/block" name="testmodule" template="newpage/content.phtml"/> 
   </reference> 
</testmodule_index_sayHello>
```

If you don't have block of your module then you can use `core/template` as block type

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes to make to the existing **config.xml** file. Since now we are using layouts, we will create our own layout file for our module. Lets name our module’s layout file as **test.xml**. We will place it in our theme/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Excellence_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Excellence_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
        <layout>  <!-- New Section Added -->
            <updates>
                <test>
                    <file>test.xml</file> <!-- This is name of the layout file for this module -->
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <test>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <test>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Helper</class>
            </test>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now create the **test.xml** file in your theme layout folder. Like in my case its **app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/test.xml** or if you have create your own theme, put the layout file there. Here are the contents of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <test_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/test" name="test" template="test/test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </test_index_index>
</layout>
```

The explanation of this layout file is given previously here. So the block we used is **“test/test”** which equal class **Excellence_Test_Block_Test** and phtml file used is **test/test.phtml**
So we will create a phtml file in location **app/design/frontend/default/default/templates/test/test.phtml**

```
<?php
    echo $this->getContent();
?>
```

In the file, we are calling a function getContent(); this function is to be declared in the block **Test.php** block file. As we have seen previous, the $this variable here is actually an object of our block class, which we define as ‘type’ in our **layout.xml**. Just to confirm you write below code in your phtml file.

```
<?php echo get_class($this); ?>
```

The output should be Excellence_Test_Block_Test.
Now create the file **Test.php** at location **app/code/local/Excellence/Test/Block/Test.php**

```
<?php
class Excellence_Test_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getContent()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Now, to call all these layouts we need to make some changes in the **IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Excellence_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();  //This function read all layout files and loads them in memory
        $this->renderLayout(); //This function processes and displays all layout phtml and php files.
    }
}
```

Open the url www.your-magento.com/test/ again and it will again print ‘helloword’.